Where can I find the resource id of an Azure function app in the Azure portal?
I am trying to find the Resource id of an Azure function app in the Azure web portal but cant seem to find it anywhere? For most other services it is either in endpoints, configuration or properties but I cant seem to find it for an Azure function app in the Azure portal?
I tried checking all the panes of the Azure function app resource.

In Function App Overview tab, click on JSON view (usually on the far right hand side of the screen) and check the "id" in the JSON. That's your Function App's resource id.

@GauravMantri Thanks, that way I can get it. Please post this as an answer and I can select it as the accepted answer.

To see the resource id of the Function App (or any other Azure resource for that matter), open up that resource in Azure Portal, navigate to Overview tab and then click on JSON view link (it is usually on the far right hand side).

This would open up a panel with the JSON for your resource.

Check out the id in there. That's the resource id of your resource.
